# Matplotlib plt.text latex error message - empty string?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, latex

Matplotlib 3.0.3 gives me a latex error message for the following minimal example, in particular for the third text (`r'a' + '\n'`). Such error messages when using raw and non-raw string mixtures never occurred for me until today and I don't know where the empty bytestring (b'' ?) is.

UPDATE: The reason why I did not get this before is that this time I forgot to remove the trailing newline, usually I have non-empty strings after the `\n`.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'text.usetex': True,
                            'text.latex.preamble': [r'\boldmath'],
                            'text.latex.unicode': True,
                            })

plt.text(0.3,0.3,r'a')
plt.text(0.4,0.4,'2\n3')
plt.text(0.5,0.5,r'a' + '\n')
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 519, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 402, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1649, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2628, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 754, in draw
    mtext=mtext)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 233, in draw_tex
    Z = texmanager.get_grey(s, size, self.dpi)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 420, in get_grey
    pngfile = self.make_png(tex, fontsize, dpi)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 385, in make_png
    "-T", "tight", "-o", pngfile, dvifile], tex)
  File "/scratch/seismo_proxauf/.conda/envs/proxconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 307, in _run_checked_subprocess
    exc=exc.output.decode('utf-8')))
RuntimeError: dvipng was not able to process the following string:
b''
Here is the full report generated by dvipng:
/home/proxauf/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/42633c70deab784e69bea3162672804e.dvi: No such file or directory
This is dvipng 1.14 Copyright 2002-2010 Jan-Ake Larsson
```

PS: I am aware that the `text.latex.unicode rcparam` is deprecated, but right now this should not be an issue yet, I hope.

Comment: I guess `\n` results in two separate processes that are handled, one of which is empty in the last case. Putting e.g. `r'a' + '\n' + r'b'` does work.

Comment: Indeed it does. But suppose I wanted to have an empty line at the end. Do I really have to write `r'a' + '\n' + r' '`?

Comment: The reason by the way why I don't use the latex `\\\` is that I don't want the latex indentation from the second line onwards..